# Simplify $7\arctan^2\varphi+2\arctan^2\varphi^3-\arctan^2\varphi^5$

Tags: trigonometry, golden-ratio

Let $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ (the golden ratio).
How can I simplify the following expression?
$$7\arctan^2\varphi+2\arctan^2\varphi^3-\arctan^2\varphi^5$$

Comment: What work have you done in attempt to solve this problem? You should post that here as well.

Comment: [Wolfram doesn't seem to know what to do with it.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7arctan%5E2%28%CF%86%29%2B2arctan%5E2%28%CF%86%5E3%29%E2%88%92arctan%5E2%28%CF%86%5E5%29) Of course, that doesn't mean it can't be simplified, but are you sure it can be? Was the question posed in a mathematics text or something?

Comment: This is trigonometry identities. For instance, note that $\cos(72)=1/(2\phi)$

Comment: A maybe-not-so-crazy idea is to write $\arctan x$ as $\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan x$ then exploit the properties of the Taylor series of $\arctan x$ *and* $\arctan^2 x$ evaluated at $x=\frac{1}{\varphi},\frac{1}{\varphi^3},\frac{1}{\varphi^5}$. There are too many identities involving harmonic numbers, dilogarithms and the golden ratio for this one to not belong to them.

Comment: Fixed. If it helps: ${\varphi}^3=2\varphi+1$ and ${\varphi}^5=5\varphi+3$

Comment: For the record, here's a spin-off question on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/210167/arctangents-of-odd-powers-of-the-golden-ratio

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We will use a well-known[$^{[1]}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Arctangent_addition_formula) formula for sum of arctangents:
$$\arctan u + \arctan v = \arctan \left( \frac{u+v}{1-uv} \right) \pmod \pi\tag1$$
The exact equality holds for $uv<1$, for other values there is additional term — an integer multiple of $\pi$ (it is easy to determine in each case).

Using this formula, we can establish the following identities:
$$\begin{align}
\arctan\varphi\phantom{^1}&=\frac\pi2-\frac12\,\arctan2,\tag2\\
\arctan\varphi^3&=\frac\pi4+\frac12\,\arctan2,\tag3\\
\arctan\varphi^5&=\pi-\frac32\,\arctan2.\tag4
\end{align}$$
Plugging these into the original expression in the question and expanding parentheses, we can see that all $\arctan2$ terms cancel, and we get the result
$$7\arctan^2\varphi+2\arctan^2\varphi^3-\arctan^2\varphi^5=\frac{7\pi^2}8.\tag5$$

Comment: (+1) Great. That was fairly simple! As a matter of fact, everything needed is: $$ (1+i\phi)^2 = \left(-\frac{1}{2}+i\right)(1+\sqrt{5}).$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That was a very nice problem! It looks like higher integer powers of $\varphi$ cannot be expressed as rational linear combination of $\pi$ and $\arctan2$, but some (not all) of them can if we add more $\arctan n$ terms, and for some a zero linear combination with several $\arctan\varphi^n$ terms exists. It would be great to analyze this behavior deeper.

Comment: For example, $\displaystyle\arctan\varphi^{11}=\frac{5\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\,\arctan{2}-\arctan{5}-\arctan{34}.$

Comment: Super!   noticed that $\tan (\, 2 \arctan(\phi^{2n+1}) \,)\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Ah, OK,  $\tan (\, 2 \arctan(\phi^{2n+1}) \,)= - \frac{2 F_{2n}}{F_{2n}^2 + F_{2n+1}^2 -1}$

Comment: Which equals $-\frac{2}{L_{2n+1}}$, with $(L_n)$ the Lucas sequence. Pretty nice.

Answer (score 6):

The answer of  @Vladimir Reshetnikov: is hard to improve on, so we'll try to answer some of the questions posed in the comments.

If $\phi=\frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the positive root of $x^2 - x-1=0$ then 
\begin{eqnarray}
\tan(2 \arctan(\phi^n)) = \frac{2\phi^n}{ 1- \phi^{2n}} = \begin{cases} -\frac{2}{L_{n}} \text{ if $n$ odd} \\
-\frac{2}{F_{n}\sqrt{5}} \text{ if $n$ even } 
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

where $(F_n)$ is the Fibonacci sequence and $(L_n)$ is the Lucas sequence.

Indeed, for every $v$ we have
$$(1+ iv)^2 = 1- v^2 + 2 i v= -v\cdot ( v -\frac{1}{v} - 2 i)$$
Now consider $v = \phi^n$. We get 
$$(1+ i \phi^n)^2 = - \phi^n\cdot ( \phi^n - \phi^{-n} - 2 i)$$
Note that $\phi$, $-\frac{1}{\phi}$ are the roots of $x^2 - x -1=0$. Therefore, if $n$ odd then $\phi^n - \phi^{-n}= \phi^n + \left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^n=L_n$, while if $n$ even then $\phi^n - \phi^{-n} = \phi^n - \left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^n= F_n \sqrt{5}$ .

Assume $n$ is odd. In order to write $2\arctan(\phi^n)$ as a combination of several $\arctan$'s of rational numbers, we decompose the number $L_n - 2 i$ in the Gaussian integers. It appears that for $n >5$ the number $L_n - 2 i$ keeps involving some distinct Gaussian primes from the previous ones.

Assume now $n$ is even. We need to decompose the number $2 + F_{n} \sqrt{-5}$ into some products of elements. Note that in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ the decomposition into irreducibles is not unique, so we have some problems.

Answer (score 3):

As a preliminary result,

$$\frac{(1+i\phi)^7(1+i\phi^3)^2}{(1+i\phi^5)}=(-5+10i)(7+3\sqrt{5})\tag{1}$$
gives, switching to arguments,
$$ 7\arctan\phi+2\arctan\phi^3-\arctan\phi^5 = 3\pi-\arctan 2. \tag{2} $$
In the same way,
$$ 7\arctan\phi^{-1}+2\arctan\phi^{-3}-\arctan\phi^{-5} = \pi+\arctan 2. \tag{3} $$

In order to deal with the squared arctangent with Parseval-like techniques, it may be useful to recall that the Fourier transform of the arctangent function is given by $i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{e^{-|s|}}{s}$. Keep working.